# AFNetworking GET 3.0 crashing

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Can anyone see why this code is failing? My url is correct and I've been through every line and read the docs, but still it is crashing. Thanks very much.

```
+ (void) fetchQuoteArray {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseURLString, @"getQuotes.php"];
    NSLog(@"url: %@", urlString);

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    [manager GET : urlString
      parameters : nil
        progress : nil
        success : ^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"success");
     }

          failure : ^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"SharedQuoteFetcher Failure:");
     }];

}
```

**Log Output**

> url: http://www.example.com/mobile/getQuotes.php
>   -[AFHTTPSessionManager GET:parameters:progress:success:failure:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8fd04431e0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AFHTTPSessionManager
>   GET:parameters:progress:success:failure:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x7f8fd04431e0'

Comment: this is the bug in AFNtework , see this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3239

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried this. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fault of Xcode,you should clean build folder(or delete your DerivedData folder,Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> Locations -> Derived Data).Because Xcode didn't fully clean the older AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

try this code , ithink its character coding problem , hope it work :

```
+ (void) fetchQuoteArray {

    NSString *path= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseURLString, @"getQuotes.php"];

NSLog(@"url: %@", urlString);

NSString *urlstring= [path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    [manager GET : urlString
      parameters : nil
        progress : nil
        success : ^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"success");
     }

          failure : ^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"SharedQuoteFetcher Failure:");
     }];

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It didn't work, unfortunately. I get the exact same error.

Comment: Can you post the real url ?